# ios opengles sample texture error （use stb_image）while android is ok

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, rendering

I use stb_image load texture, such as

```
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
int width, height, nrComponents;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);

GLenum format;
if (nrComponents == 1) {
    format = GL_RED;
} else if (nrComponents == 3) {
    format = GL_RGB;
} else {
    format = GL_RGBA;
}

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

The same code in android is ok, while in ios the rendering result get some problem:
[image: ios]

[image: android]

if set stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(false):
[image]

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with the image loading code? The texture content looks fine - I suspect your texture coordinates are wrong.

Comment: its ok if I sample texture to a square, so it may be not an issues with stb_image.   But I still very confused why its ok in android with the same code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that GLKView not set depth buffer, just add one line code : `view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;`

Answer (score 0):

It may be the depth error, while depth is culling off